# Erro "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in"

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou criando um formulário de insert para cadastro, mas quando clico no botão ele está me apresentando erro:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto Beleza e Harmonia\Beleza e Harmonia - site\php\cadastro.php on line 25

O que será que está pegando?

cadastro.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>cadastro concluido</title>
    </head>

    <body>


<?php 
include("../php/conexao.php");


$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$ende = $_POST['endereco'];
$tel = $_POST['telefone'];
$comple = $_POST['complemento'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$mail = $_POST['emails'];
$nume = $_POST['numero'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(nome, telefone, endereco, numero, complemento, email, login, senha) VALUES('$nome', '$tel', '$ende', '$nume', '$comple', '$mail', '$login', '$senha')";

        $result = mysqli_query($bd, $sql) or die ('Error querying database.');

        mysqli_close($bd);  
?>

    </body>

</html>
```

conexao.php:

```
<?php 

$host = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$bd="admin_site";



$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);


if($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Falha na conexão: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
}


?>
```

linha 25:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($bd, $sql) or die ('Error querying database.');
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Praticamente todas as funções do mysqli usam como primeiro parâmetro o "link" de conexão com o banco.

Você faz:

```
$bd="admin_site";
```

E tenta usar

```
$result = mysqli_query($bd, $sql);
```

Sendo que o 1º parâmetro deve ser a conexão, e não o nome do DB.

O correto seria:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql );
```

#### Sugestão de melhoria:

Para não fazer uma confusão danada, sugiro trocar o nome do link/conexão para `$con` ou `$link`, que são muito comuns em documentação e exemplos:

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);
```

e depois:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
```

Answer (score 8):

O problema está em:

```
$result = mysqli_query($bd, $sql)
```

Vocês está passando o valor de `$db` como parâmetro, mas `$bd` é apenas uma `string`, tenta passar como parâmetro a variável `$mysqli`

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) é esperado um [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) como primeiro argumento da função `mysqli_query`